# Toggling ProxyCreation in EF7 under new configuration

Tags: entity-framework, configuration, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So in EF6, one could disable proxy creation like so:

```
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

From what I could find, the configuration scheme under EF7 has changed, but I cannot find anything on how to do so. I went through https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html and even analyzed the DbContextOptionsBuilder object, but cannot find anything on it.

Am I going about ti the wrong way or is there something im missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>EF7</strike> EF Core 1.0 does not do proxy creation, so accordingly, there is no configuration option for this. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/997

Comment: Haha that would explain why I couldnt find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework Core 2.1 starts to support Lazy load. Please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading

Here is recent question with answers from stackoverflow:
[What is the equivalent of .Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled in EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234943/what-is-the-equivalent-of-configuration-proxycreationenabled-in-ef-core/55235856#55235856)