# DbContext does not contain a definition for Configuration - EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm developing a application using EF Core. I want disable proxy creation, but when I try to use the command an error appears.

My Db Context class:

```
public class BMContext : DbContext
{
     public BMContext()
     {
          this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
     }
}
```

And the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'BMContext' does not contain a definition for 'Configuration' and no accessible extension method 'Configuration' accepting a first argument of type 'BeerMakersContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggling ProxyCreation in EF7 under new configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222699/toggling-proxycreation-in-ef7-under-new-configuration)

Comment: Proxy creation doesn't exist in EF Core by default. You have to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` to use it. So there is no real need to disable it (since you can just not install that package).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Gabriel Luci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202807/gabriel-luci):

You need to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` Package.

1. In Visual studio go to `Tools` ➤ `NuGet Package Manager` ➤ `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...`
2. In opened window go to `Browse` tab and search for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` package.
3. Click it and on the right choose the project you want to install it in (I suppose it's for server) and press `Install`

Comment: I am facing the same issue, even I installed Proxies package,