# What is the equivalent of .Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

What is the equivalent of .Configuration in Entity Framework Core? Receiving error below

**Code Examples:**

```
        List<DocumentStatus> documentStatuses;
        using (var db = new ModelDBContext())
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            documentStatuses = db.DocumentStatus.ToList();
        }


        using (var db = new ModelDBContext())
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            //Expression<Func<Owner, bool>> predicate = query => true;
```

db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled

**Error Messages throughout:**

> Error  CS1061  'ModelDBContext' does not contain a definition for 'Configuration' and no accessible extension method 'Configuration' accepting a first argument of type 'ModelDBContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on Entity Framework Core docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data, from EF Core 2.1, there is a way to enable Lazy Loading with or without proxy.

**1. Lazy Loading with Proxy:**

a. Make sure your navigation property are defined as "virtual"

b. Install the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies package

c. Enable it with a call to UseLazyLoadingProxies

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
```

Or enable it when using AddDbContext

```
.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(
    b => b.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
          .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));
```

**2. Lazy Loading without Proxy:**

a. Injecting the ILazyLoader service into an entity, as described in Entity Type Constructors. For example:

```
public class Blog
{
    private ICollection<Post> _posts;

    public Blog()
    {
    }

    private Blog(ILazyLoader lazyLoader)
    {
        LazyLoader = lazyLoader;
    }

    private ILazyLoader LazyLoader { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts
    {
        get => LazyLoader.Load(this, ref _posts);
        set => _posts = value;
    }
}
```

---

**By default, EF Core won't use lazy load with proxy, but if you want to use proxy, please follow 1st approach.**

Comment: then I should just utilize second approach, and not even do anything or even the word proxy, correct? thanks again