# Entity Framework Core Doesn't load some of the related object

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm working on project based on ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework core.
I use generic repository pattern here. When I retrieve on specific object few object are retrieved with the same but some are not load. Please refer the following screen shots.

Please refer the following for the pattern implementation:

[image]

Please refer the debugger view below:

[image]

Above image shows that this object retrieves the "Offer" but not "Location".

Refer the following image for the "OfferLocation" class:

[image]

Any ideas about this situation?

Comment: Please, don't post _images_ of code and errors, but text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are requesting `Offer` and tell the EF.Core to include `OfferLocations` property. The `OfferLocation` references back the requested `Offer` object this why it got set. If you want to have `Location` to be included in this request you have to use `ThenInclude` method right after `Include` one. E.g. if you were using the database context to retrieve the data it could look like this:

```cs
context.Offers
    .Include(o => o.OfferLocations)
        .ThenInclude(ol => ol.Location)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == id);
```

But with the generic repository approach you pass the collection of include expressions as the `Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpression` which obviously doesn't let you use `ThenInclude`.

You can use the approach described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374252/how-to-write-repository-method-for-theninclude-in-ef-core-2).

```cs
public Task<TEntity> FirstOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null,
                                         Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null,
                                         CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.DbSet;

    if (include != null)
    {
        query = include(query);
    }

    if (predicate != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(predicate);
    }

    return query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var offer = await this.unitOfWork.Offers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(
    predicate: o => o.Id == id,
    include: source => source
        .Include(o => o.Partner)
        .Include(o => o.SubCategory)
        .Include(o => o.Category)
        .Include(o => o.OfferItems)
        .Include(o => o.OfficeLocations)
            .ThenInclude(ol => ol.Location));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use this package.

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies

And in the context use this line of code.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring (DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies ();
}
```

This package automatic include when you use other Collection.

Comment: for learn how to use go to link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234943/what-is-the-equivalent-of-configuration-proxycreationenabled-in-ef-core

Comment: As you see on the screenshot it loads one of the object(Offer) which is in this collection, but it doesn't load the "Location" object.